# How to retrieve objects from mongoose array of schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having trouble finding list of documents from Mongoose. I have a favorites schema as follows.

```
    var favoriteSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  dishes: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Dish'
    }
  ]
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

In MongoDB shell, I get a list of Dish objects' ids like shown below. You can see two ObjectIds in the dishes array.

```
> db.favorites.findOne({"user": ObjectId("59e8d94669e02a0f21eae4b5") });
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ed9964b55536153410bd46"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-10-23T07:30:04.743Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-23T07:25:24.922Z"),
    "dishes" : [
        ObjectId("59ecafdeefa2180e50dc730b"),
        ObjectId("59ecafdeefa2180e50dc730c")
    ],
    "__v" : 4,
    "user" : ObjectId("59e8d94669e02a0f21eae4b5")
}
```

In favoriteRouter, I have a method like this. Does it work for populating array objects?

```
favoriteRouter.route('/')
.get((req, res, next) => {
  Favorites.findOne({'user': ObjectId(req.user._id)})
  .populate('user')
  .populate('dishes')
  .exec((err, favorites) => {
    console.log(favorites);
    if(err) throw err;
    res.json(favorites);
  });
});
```

In response, I am getting object with only one dish populated with its values.

```
{
  "_id":"59ed9964b55536153410bd46",
  "updatedAt":"2017-10-23T07:30:04.743Z",
  "createdAt":"2017-10-23T07:25:24.922Z",
  "__v":4,
  "user":{
  "_id":"59e8d94669e02a0f21eae4b5",
  "username":"username",
  "password": "password",
  "__v":0,
},
"dishes":
  [
    {
      "_id":"59ecafdeefa2180e50dc730b",
      "updatedAt":"2017-10-22T14:49:02.444Z",
      "createdAt":"2017-10-22T14:49:02.444Z",
      "name":"name",
      "price":499,
      "description":"Some description",
      "__v":0
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The query is not wrong, but the data will be. This is what happens when there is no matching data in the referenced collection. Take a look in your `"dishes"` collection, and discover that the other `ObjectId` value does not exist.

Comment: Thanks Neil, You were spot on! it worked!